# add prefix to a harvard-style citation call-out, as in "(e.g. Abe et al., 1999)"

Tags: citing, harvard-style

The `iucr` document class, prescribed for IUCr journals, includes the `harvard` citation management package. How can I change `\cite{Abe99}` so that "Abe et al., 1999" is preceded by "e.g.", within the parentheses?

Comment: No, I cannot switch, since I have to use the journal's style file iucr.cls.

Comment: Ah too bad. If you are using a journal class to submit to a publisher they probably won't like you hacking their packages either, so you are in a bit of a fix. (BTW: You may want to clarify that you are using a publisher *class*, I read the "in iucr style" as referring to `iucr.bst`, i.e. a BibTeX style and not a document class. An example document would be even better and would have avoided that confusion entirely.)

Comment: @Mico Ah, I totally missed that. Good catch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `harvard` citation management package provides the `\citeaffixed` macro. This macro would appear to provide a ready-made solution for your formatting query. E.g., assuming that `\cite{Abe99}` produces `(Abe et al., 1999)`, then

```
\citeaffixed{Abe99}{e.g.,}
```

produces the following citation call-out:

```
(e.g., Abe et al., 1999)
```

Answer (score 2):

Had there not been the pertinent macro `\citeaffixed` (see the accepted answer by @Mico), then a fallback would have been

```
(e.~g.\ \citename{Abe99}, \citeyear*{Abe99})
```

See the comment below for yet another solution.

Comment: In that case I think `\harvardparenthesis{none}` and `(e.g. \cite{Abe99})` would be slightly nicer for general use, but for a one-off you may use whatever you like (untested ...). Note that `\citename` and `\citeyear` don't interact with other `\cite`s in the way `\cite` does.

Comment: Wouldn't `\harvardparenthesis{none}` change the style for all citations to come? I need the "e.g." in just one place.

Comment: Maybe you can change it back after the citation with `\harvardparenthesis{round}` (not sure if it is a preamble command). I would probably wrap this up in a wrapper command with its own parentheses.

Comment: For unknown reasons, the solution based on `\harvardparenthesis` prevents linebreaks within the citation, whereas my solution allows them.